# Increase soft limit for stack size in Solaris 11

Tags: oracle, unix, solaris, sunos, oracle19c

How can we increase the soft limit of 'stack size' system wide in solaris 11?

I have increased other ulimits by adding them in /etc/system file. What is the variable to set for stack size? 
If there is any other way, please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to do this using Projects. 
I added a project with name user.oracle and added "max-stack-size,basic" for that project which was the default project for Oracle user.